# IDE integration with custom language implemented with Antlr4

Tags: ide, antlr4

We wrote a custom language using Antlr4 and I was wondering what tools (open source will be perfect) are available to create an IDE for this language implemented by antlr4. I'd like to make an IDE that supports syntax highlighting, syntax/error checker,  autocompletion and project template.

However, I have looked at Xtext, Spoofax, SyntaxEditor, unfortunately they only support Antlr3. Visual Studio Pro works but not every end user of our language is able to purchase Visual Studio Pro. The express version does not support SDK so it won't work.

I have not found anything positive yet, does anybody has already done one similar based on a Antlr4 grammar ???

Thanks a lot

Comment: Does Visual Studio Shell work? It's free...

Comment: As you already discovered - while others may have not - there's a similar question on google-groups: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/antlr-discussion/EBZDY25lwB0/tleZ4zxyCX8J